# Navigate to previous activity with back button in title bar

Tags: android

I want to add back button in my android application.For this in subactivity i have added this code

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);
     getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // getting values from selected ListItem
                        String FC_DATE = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fc_date)).getText()
                                .toString();

                        // Starting new intent
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                ForecastActivity.class);
                        // sending lat/long to next activity

                        in.putExtra(TAG_FC_DATE, FC_DATE);
                        in.putExtra(TAG_LAT, LAT);
                        in.putExtra(TAG_LONG, LONGITUDE);
                        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                        startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                    }
                });
```

With this code i m able to see the back button in title bar. but when i have added backpressed method,It will not returned to the previous activity...Plz help me...

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() 
            {
             this.startActivity(new Intent(LocationActivity.this,AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.class));  

                return;  
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think onBackPressed is referred to the button of the phone itself.

With ActionBar you should use this listener

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case putYourIdHere:
        startActivity(new Intent(LocationActivity.this,AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.class));  
        return true;  
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is showing me the error that:Duplicate method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) in type LocationActivity.I have edited my code in my question.

Comment: Where did you put onOptionItemSeleccted?

Comment: Post the complete code. Anyway you have to put it in the activity class at the same "level" of onCreate ect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onOptionsItemSelected method to catch the up button:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home)
    {
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown.        
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I have already called this method for Overflow menu in my code..so how can i override it?

Comment: If you already overwrite this method, can't you just add the if(id==android.R.id.home)?

Answer (score 0):

1.In onCreate() method , add

```
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_launcher); //custom app icon
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

2.Override onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

```
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id){
        case R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;

        //handle other actions
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

3.Specify following attribute in manifest android:parentActivityName=" logical parent of the activity /name of activity to be launched" in your SubActivity

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SubActivity"
        android:label="SubActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.actionbardemo.MainActivity"
         >

    </activity>
```